# What is the difference between md5sum output and Python hashlib output?

Tags: python, bash, md5, gravatar

Why is the output of `hashlib.md5().hexdigest()` different than `md5sum` and `openssl` output?

```
$ echo "test string" | md5sum
f299060e0383392ebeac64b714eca7e3  -
$ echo "test string" | openssl dgst -md5
(stdin)= f299060e0383392ebeac64b714eca7e3
$ python
Python 2.7.15rc1 (default, Apr 15 2018, 21:51:34)
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from hashlib import md5
>>> print(md5("test string").hexdigest())
6f8db599de986fab7a21625b7916589c
```

I noticed this while trying to generate an md5 digest for use with Gravatar. The Python `hashlib` output works but the `md5sum` and `openssl` outputs do not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`echo` adds an implicit newline by default.

```
$ echo -n "test string" | openssl dgst -md5
(stdin)= 6f8db599de986fab7a21625b7916589c
```

Comment: I *knew* I was missing something. Thanks! I'll accept as soon as it lets me.

Comment: `printf '%s' "test string"` if you are using a shell or `echo` that doesn't support `-n`.